# Convert NFA to DFA

Tags: computability, automata, finite-automata

I have to convert the following NFA's into the equivalent DFA's.

[image]

I have done the following:

[image]

Could you tell me if it is correct??

Comment: @AlexR The Automata tag description: Automata Theory, including abstract machines, grammars, parsing, grammatical inference, transducers, and finite-state techniques. Thus, also this question *could* be in computer science, it is also on topic at math.stackexchange.

Answer (score 1):

Your first conversion is correct.

You need to label your initial node in your second automaton. You also need to consider the epsilon-closure when creating new states - e.g. {1,3} should not be a node, as it is possible to reach state 2, from state 1, under an epsilon-transition.

Comment: I edited my initial post and labeled the initial node at the second automaton. Is this correct?? Could you explain to me further what you said about the epsilon-closure??

Comment: From the set of states {1,2}, under a, it is possible to reach any of {1,2,3}. That is, you can reach 2 under an epsilon-transition from 1. You've taken the epsilon-closure in the creation of your initial state, but you haven't in the creation of further states.

Comment: @Mary: Because of the $\epsilon$-transition from $1$ to $2$, any state in the DFA that contains $1$ must automatically contain $2$. You can’t have a state $\{1,3\}$: it must be $\{1,2,3\}$.

Answer (score 0):

The first is ok, the second is more like :

[image]